# Disadvantages of self signed and cross signed certificates?

Tags: certificates

Can anyone explain what are the disadvantages or loopholes in self signed and cross signed certificates?

Comment: Self-signed certs have an obvious problem. Are you aware of the weaknesses in self-signed certs (it's pretty easy to look up)?

Comment: You will find already lots of [questions asking about the security of self-signed certificates](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=security+self-signed+certificates) here. Please look at these Q+A and then be more specific about what questions still remain. As it is know I consider this question too broad.